# The function is not re-scrape with R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I'm having trouble running the function multiple times.

More precisely, the function works well:

- enter the site
- search for the keyword [MPM.search]
- load the page
- another function scrapes and cleans the result [data.recovery]
- create a CSV

```
data.recovery <- function(i) {

       prod <- read_html(i)

       title <- prod %>% 
                  html_nodes(".mapping-name.limit-width") %>% 
                  html_text() %>% 
                  data.frame()

       colnames(title) <- "results"
      
      title$results <- gsub("^[^[:alnum:]]+",'',title$results)
      title$results <- gsub("\\\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$", "", title$results)
      
      return(title)
    }
    
data <- data.frame()
    
MPM.search <- function(i) {
     
      clean.insert<- remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", "#smartSearchInput")
      clean.insert$clearElement()
      

      prod.insert<- remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", "#smartSearchInput") 
      prod.insert$sendKeysToElement(list(i))
      
      clicksearch<- remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", "#smartSearchButton")
      clicksearch$clickElement()
    
      
      prod.page <-remote_driver$getPageSource()[[1]]
      
      title <-  unlist(sapply(prod.page, FUN = data.recovery, USE.NAMES = F))
                          
      data.MPM <- rbind(data, i = i, title)
      return(data.MPM)
    }
```

But when I execute the function, on a new word, the data of the previous word remain loaded and I have to
rerun the function again to scrape the data generated by the new word.

Example: I enter the word "Asus", load data of the word "Asus", scrape and create the csv. So far everything
well. However, when I enter a word, for example "MSI", it repeats all the steps but returns a data-frame (csv)
with the old word "Asus". In order for me to get a new dataframe, with the new word "MSI" I have to execute the
function again.

Where am I wrong? Does it also depend on the HTML code of the page? How can I do? Thanks to anyone who can help me !!

Comment: Is the website public?

Comment: Hi @QHarr, thanks for your interest. No, the website belongs to a management software that I use in my work

Comment: @QHarr do you think this is a problem? I am a beginner and I really don't know where to start

Comment: Hi @StefanoMariaDeFrancesco I suggest you to implement a couple of sleep. 
For example, I will write a  between      
 `clicksearch$clickElement()`

`Sys.sleep(2)`   

 `prod.page <-remote_driver$getPageSource()[[1]] ` When you wirte some in selenium you have to think that it is a 'person', so It needs of time to take answer and so on. Think about it. ;) best!

Comment: yes, thanks @Earl Mascetti. In the end I understood it